# Defining indefinite integration algebraically

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, integration

The following is a sketch of an idea that I have, and my question boils down to asking how to make the following equivalent to the standard definition of the indefinite Riemann integral.

Put $D = \{g:\mathbf R\to \mathbf R\mid \text{$g$ is differentiable}\}$ and $C = \{f:\mathbf R\to \mathbf R\mid \text{$f$ is continuous}\}$. (Perhaps $D$ and $C$ are groups under addition. Conceivably, they could be vector spaces as well, and ideally an answer to this question will touch on which algebraic structure is more appropriate.) If we define the map $\varphi: D\to C$ by $\varphi(g) = g'$, then the kernel of $\varphi$ is $K$, the set of all constant functions $\mathbf R\to \mathbf R$. Can we define the indefinite integral of $f\in C$ as an element $g+K$ of the quotient $D/K$, where $g' = f$? (The quotient may be a quotient group or a quotient vector space, or perhaps something else—again hopefully an answer to this question will address this in some detail.) If something like this is possible, what do we need to make this construction rigorous?

To be clear, I am approaching this problem from the point of view of someone who thinks that this could work, given *something like, but perhaps not exactly* what I have written down as a foundation, and I am relying on others to fill in the details, including points such as the appropriate domain/codomain of this function, whether the sets $D$ and $C$ are groups or vector spaces, etc.

Comment: What makes you think this is not rigorous? Seems pretty clear and well-defined to me. The question is what do you want to do with it. The quotient is a quotient vector space -- which is also a quotient group (*as all quotient vector spaces are* -- after all, vector spaces are just abelian groups with extra structure).

Comment: You should be careful with the domain/codomain - differentiable functions do not have continuous derivatives in general.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks for your comment; I edited my question a bit to get at what I am trying to know.

Comment: This is definitely not equivalent to any treatment of anything. How do you know that the map is surjective? Moreover, the map cannot have that codomain

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks for the comment; I think it may help future readers understand my question better. You have stated my point: what I have here is a sketch that I am trying to make into a working equivalence of the standard treatment of indefinite integration, and my question asks for help filling in the details, one of which is this issue with domain/codomain. It is one aspect of my idea I am trying to treat.

Comment: The problem is that what you wrote is not a formulation of the Riemann integral in any sensible sense. You should explain what you are trying to do, in as concrete terms as you can. It will help immensely if you clear such doubts as whether the set of differentiable functions is a vector space or not before embarking on reformulating anything